# Lex compilation error of IOS example of opencascade library in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, opencascade

I'm trying to build an IOS example of OPENCascade library on MacOs. Xcode version were used: 10.2, 10, 3, 11.1. RIght now I'm getting the following types of errors:

```
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:60: bad character: =
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:62: name defined twice
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:63: bad character: {
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:65: bad character: }
../occt_lib/src/BRepFeat/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.lxx:66: premature EOF
flex: error deleting output file ../project.build/DerivedSources/BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.yy.cxx
Command ../XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex failed with exit code 1
```

Possible reasons in my opinion: 
1) I don't have all of the files in the project (I've checked it, so it shouldn't be a reason) 
2) Xcode doesn't treat .lxx files in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Within OCCT file name conversions, .lxx is an extension for inline C++ header files, included by co-named .hxx header files. **BRepFeat** package has no any .yacc/.lex files, thus **BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole.yy.cxx** should not exist at all.

It looks like the issue is somewhere within building routine (CMake or Tcl script) generating XCode project / Makefile. It is unclear from question if an issue happens on building OCCT itself (and which steps have been taken) or while building iOS sample (is it the one coming with OCCT or written from scratch?).

CMake build for OCCT can be configured via the following cross-compilation toolchain and pseudo bash script:
https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake

```
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
aFreeType=$HOME/freetype-2.7.1-ios
  cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
  -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="$HOME/ios-cmake.git/ios.toolchain.cmake" \
  -D PLATFORM:STRING="OS64" \
  -D ARCHS:STRING="arm64" \
  -D IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:STRING="$IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" \
  -D ENABLE_VISIBILITY:BOOL="TRUE" \
  -D CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS:BOOL="OFF" \
  -D CMAKE_CXX_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS:BOOL="OFF" \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Release" \
  -D BUILD_LIBRARY_TYPE:STRING="Static" \
  -D INSTALL_DIR:PATH="work/occt-ios-install" \
  -D INSTALL_DIR_INCLUDE:STRING="inc" \
  -D INSTALL_DIR_LIB:STRING="lib" \
  -D INSTALL_DIR_RESOURCE:STRING="src" \
  -D INSTALL_NAME_DIR:STRING="@executable_path/../Frameworks" \
  -D 3RDPARTY_FREETYPE_DIR:PATH="$aFreeType" \
  -D 3RDPARTY_FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2:FILEPATH="$aFreeType/include" \
  -D 3RDPARTY_FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build:FILEPATH="$aFreeType/include" \
  -D 3RDPARTY_FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DIR:PATH="$aFreeType/lib" \
  -D USE_FREEIMAGE:BOOL="OFF" \
  -D BUILD_MODULE_Draw:BOOL="OFF" \
  "/Path/To/OcctSourceCode"
aNbJobs="$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)"
make -j $aNbJobs
make install
```